# Manage virtual machines of different virtualization engines uniformly

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I have several VMs hosted by VMware and several VMs hosted by HyperV. I'm wondering if there is any application/library/API that allows to treat these VMs in a uniform way not depending on virtualization backend? For example I want to be able start/stop VMs or run a particular script in the guest OS? I know about libvirt but didn't find any analogues that support HyperV.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Micosoft SCVMM for example does that (System Center Virtual Machine Manager). Given your (low) req2uirements it likely is too expensive though. It allows you to do a LOT more.

Comment: SSVMM doesn't seem to support VMware-hosted VMs

Comment: I want my scripts/configs to stay the same if I move one of my VMs from VMware to HyperV

Comment: Well, reading is liely not your case - SCVMM does support VmWare hosted VM's (with limtied features, stilll). OTherwise - sorry - you now have to pay the price for multiple technologies. No technology available. I suggest you start killing either VmWare or HyperV and consolidate. Multiple tech always has administrative limitations. This is why enterprises standardize.

Comment: Or write/buy a 3rd party tool made for this.

Comment: That's what I'm asking - is there a 3rd party tool that does that

Comment: Yes, SCVMM, as TomTom has already mentioned. It's not flawless, but if you expect flawless then you've got no appreciation of what you're actually asking for.

Answer (score 0):

`libvirt` can control ESX, kvm and xen hypervisors, I think I saw plans in place for hyper-v as well.

[vcentre multi hypervisor manager](http://www.vmware.com/support/mhm/doc/vcenter-multi-hypervisor-manager-10-release-notes.html) is said to e able to cover vmware and hyper-c as well

[solarwinds virtualization manager](http://www.solarwinds.com/virtualization-manager.aspx) also has these capabilities stated in it's description

There are plenty of other options, if you google the question